# How to send string value from secondView to mainView with use popover segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopover

i want to send string value from `secondView` to `mainView` but I click OK button use this code `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and then prepare segue not working. When I want to click OK button, I send in `textfield` value to `mainView` controller.

Thanks in replies.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can use an _unwind_ segue for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Main View Controller (That contains the label) header file declare the outlet for the label:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
```

In Your `SettingsViewController.m` import your `ViewController.h`. And change the `OK` button l.ke below>

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *vCtrl = (ViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
    vCtrl.nameLabel.text  = yourTextField.text;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT:**

As OP is using `UINavigationController` and push segues for navigating, the method should be changed to:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    ViewController *vCtrl = (ViewController *)[[(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
    vCtrl.nameLabel.text  = yourTextField.text;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: @fozoglu: Let me know if you are having any issues with this code

Comment: @fozoglu: What is the crash log shown in the console ? I've done a sample app before posting my answer and it is working perfectly

Comment: 2015-01-10 12:24:49.768 popovertest[19731:587831] -[UINavigationController nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcae3781ab0
2015-01-10 12:24:49.770 popovertest[19731:587831] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController nameLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcae3781ab0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68544/discussion-between-fozoglu-and-midhun-mp).

Comment: @fozoglu: It's someone else, not you :)