# Update UILabels when dismissing a modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, segue

I'm having an issue when I want to update UILabels after dismissing a modal.
Basically I have:
A ViewController with some UILabels and UIButtons
when I touch a button, it opens a modal with a text field, I type some text into this text field which is saved into an instance of a CacheHandler I did.
Then I dismiss my modal with a button, and I'd like to see the text I typed in the UILabel.
The text is saved in the cache, I've checked. I have a method to update my labels when I call it from the custom segue, label value is null. Where am I doing wrong?

Custom segue:

```
#import "DismissModalSegue.h"
#import "CreateSqeedViewController.h"

@implementation DismissModalSegue

- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    CreateSqeedViewController *destViewController = self.destinationViewController;
    [sourceViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [destViewController updateLabels];
    }];
}

@end
```

updateLabels method:

```
- (void)updateLabels {
    NSLog(@"Updating labels: %@", [[[CacheHandler instance] createSqeed] place]);
/* displays what I want to display in my label */
    NSLog(@"%@", whatLabel.text);
/* displays null */
    whereLabel.text = [[[CacheHandler instance] createSqeed] place];
    whatLabel.text = [[[CacheHandler instance] createSqeed] sqeedDescription];
    NSString *peopleLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", [[[CacheHandler instance] createSqeed] peopleMin], [[[CacheHandler instance] createSqeed] peopleMax]];
    whoLabel.text = peopleLabel;
    whereLabel.text = [[[[CacheHandler instance] createSqeed] dateStart] description];
}
```

Comment: Why not to use unwind segue which calls a method on VC? And no need in custom segue.

Answer (score 0):

where are initialized label? Are connected with IBOutlet?
maybe call them back when they are not initialized

Comment: They are IBOutlet properties in .h and synthesised in .m.
I checked in the viewDidLoad method and they are perfectly initialised, they have a default value.

Comment: updateLabels method is called correctly? You could try using NSNotificationCenter to send a notification to call the method.

Comment: Look here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874673/how-to-send-string-value-from-secondview-to-mainview-with-use-popover-segue[/link]